How to make a tcolobox stick the bottom of the page ? (and why \vfill is not perfectly working?)
I have created a MWE where one can picture my issue.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    left   =0cm,
    right  =0cm,
    top    =0cm,
    bottom =0cm,
    paperwidth  = 521pt,
    paperheight = 384pt
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins, breakable, theorems]{tcolorbox}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newtcolorbox{Mybox}{
    %enhanced,
    arc = 0pt,
    boxrule = 0pt,
    colback = blue,
    colupper = white,
    top= 2pt,
    bottom = 1pt
}


\begin{document}

\begin{Mybox}
    Some small upper text.
\end{Mybox}

\lipsum[1]

\vspace*{\fill}%
\begin{Mybox}
    Some small lower text.
\end{Mybox}

\end{document}


In the previous image, one can see that the top tcolorbox sticks perfectly to the top but the bottom one is not (quite). How can I fix this? Note the unusual geometry.
The geometry package does not show any other spacing than bottom so I should be able to reach the bottom of the page. Is that a flaw of the \vfill then?
PS: I do not want to work with fancyhdr here since I want something far more simple.

Ok so the problem actually come from tcolorbox and the option after=0pt should be added to Mybox and this solves the problem.
If any admin is around, should I delete my question then?

I think it's better that you answer your own question.

(1) If you are trying to do presentations without know Beamer, take a look to this package. (2)  You do not need the asterisk in \vspace in this case here, and instead of \vspace{\fill} you can use simply  \vfill (3) If beamer is not option, maybe fancyhdr to place boxes as header and  footers? (4) You can also  have a perfect bottom  box without dealing with spaces with  options float, floatplacement=b. This option is only suitable  if you have a good understanding of how floats behave.

@Fran [thanks for the comment] (1) This question comes as a detail in the full class for presentation I am building. I'm avoiding Beamer because it is either too constraining or too difficult to use. (2) I corrected that in my answer. (3) I did not manage to make fancyhdr work with tcolorbox. Furthermore, I am not using complicated headers/footers so that I find my environments more convinient. (4) I did not thought of using floats and that could be a good idea! All the more that tcolorbox allows one to treat the box as floats if one asks for it.

My issue was actually caused by a spacing specific to tcolorbox (that one can find in their documentation, page 11). Therefore, to solve my issue one just need to add after=0pt as option for the tcolorbox.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[
    left   =0cm,
    right  =0cm,
    top    =0cm,
    bottom =0cm,
    paperwidth  = 521pt,
    paperheight = 384pt
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins, breakable, theorems]{tcolorbox}

\pagestyle{empty}

\newtcolorbox{Mybox}{
    %enhanced,
    arc = 0pt,
    boxrule = 0pt,
    colback = blue,
    colupper = white,
    top= 2pt,
    bottom = 1pt,
    after = 0pt
}


\begin{document}

\begin{Mybox}
    Some small upper text.
\end{Mybox}

\lipsum[1]

\vfill%
\begin{Mybox}
    Some small lower text.
\end{Mybox}

\end{document}

I also changed \vspace*{\fill} to \vfill, as suggested by Fran.
